# Как сделать появление контента без перезагрузки страницы?

Tags: html, jquery, bootstrap

Приветствую. Есть навигационная панель слева(вертикальная), используется bootstrap. Как сделать, чтобы при нажатии на разделы меню слева, справа появлялся контент этих разделов без перезагрузки страницы? Есть ли какие-то инструменты или подобные примеры реализации?

Comment: http://bootsnipp.com/snippets/featured/ajax-div-wizard

Comment: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/list-group/#javascript-behavior

Answer (score 1):

Ну если не надо контент подгружать, то можно просто за каждым пунктом меню , закрепить свой блок контента и отображать его по клику.

```js
$('.menu li').on('click',function(){
  var targetBlock = $(this).data('content');
  $('.'+targetBlock).show().siblings('.hide').hide();
});
```

```css
.conteiner{
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
}
.menu , .content{
  padding:5px;
  display:block;
  float:left;
  width:20%;
  background:#e1dede;
}
.menu li{
  cursor:pointer;
}
.content , li:hover{
  background:white;
}
.content .hide{
  display:none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class='conteiner'>
  <div class='menu'>
    <ul>
      <p>menu</p>
      <li data-content='b1'>block1</li>
      <li data-content='b2'>block2</li>
      <li data-content='b3'>block3</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class='content'>
    <p>content</p>
    <div class='b1 hide'>this content block1</div>
    <div class='b2 hide'>this content block2</div>
    <div class='b3 hide'>this content block3</div>
  </div>
</div>
```